# What is the best way to ask a Chinese person to give / leave feedback

Tags: word-choice

I am interested in finding out the best way to ask a Chinese person to give or leave me feedback about my services, on the Internet. (Like a restaurant review). I would like to ask in a respectful, polite way that gives me a good chance of them taking a moment to leave feedback.

In simple or classic Chinese, how do I do this?

Comment: 請問，您對我的服務有什麼看法？ or 請問，您對我的服務滿意嗎？ or 請問，我的服務有什麼地方需要改進嗎？

Comment: In written or spoken? Where will you put it?

Answer (score 1):

您好，请对我们的服务提出宝贵建议，谢谢！

您好，请问您对我们的服务有什么意见或建议吗？

您好，请问您对我们的服务满意吗？

您好，请问我们的菜合您的胃口吗？

Answer (score 1):

Like any other language, to obtain feedback, first thing is to be polite.
here are few tips that I think might be helpful:

- to use "你好" or "您好" to start a conversation, it's like "Hello" but "您好" is more polite
- followed by "请问_____" to politely ask a man or woman for help like
  feedback, it's like "excuse me, could you please____" in English.

For now , the beginning better to be like "你好/您好, 请问__balabala___"

Next should ask for feedback, use the following examples to fill in the blanks:

1. " 你/您(means you)对***满意吗? "——  (**** could be "the food"), this means if he is satisfied with ***? plus:***also could be "the service"(in Chinese, 服务) or "our service"(in Chinese, 我们的服务)
2. " 你/您(means you)对***有什么意见建议吗? " —— (**** same as above), this
   means if he has any suggestions or complains with ***? plus:***same as above

usually these two is enough for feedback, of course there are also a lot different ways like:

- "请问, 你/您认为我们有什么地方可以改进呢?"—— ask if he/she can give advice to improve
  our service.
- "请问, 可以对***做出评价吗?"—— ask if he/she can comment on ***.
- "请问, 可以耽误你/您几分钟时间吗?"—— ask if he/she can spend several minutes to do
  something.